# Issue in operator overloading using smart pointers

Tags: c++11, operator-overloading

I am learning smart pointers in C++11.
I am facing an compilation error with operator overloading using smart pointers.
Can someone please suggest where I am doing wrong.

Below is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class myClass
{
   private:
   string name;

   public:
   myClass() { }
   myClass(string n) : name(n)  { }

   shared_ptr<myClass> operator + (shared_ptr<myClass> &obj)
   {
      cout << "Operator Overloading" << endl; 
      shared_ptr<myClass> temp;
      temp->name = this->name;
      temp->name += obj->name;
  
      return temp;
   }

   void print()
   {
      cout << name << endl;
   }
};

int main()
{
   shared_ptr<myClass> myPtr1 = make_shared<myClass>("Hello");
   myPtr1->print();

   shared_ptr<myClass> myPtr2 = make_shared<myClass>("Operator Overloading");
   myPtr2->print();

   shared_ptr<myClass> myPtr3;
   myPtr3 = myPtr1 + myPtr2; //Calling Operator overloading
   myPtr3->print();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: When `operator+` is defined as a member function, it is expected to take one parameter, and compute the result of adding this parameter to `*this`. In other words, the expression `a + b` is interpreted as `a.operator+(b)`. You probably want to define your `operator+` as a free (non-member) function.

Comment: Also, your `operator+` seems to be trying to call itself recursively. If and when you get it to compile, you'll have an infinite recursion.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik
I have modified the "operator +" code as above. But, still I am getting compilation issues. Please suggest me

Comment: `MyClass::operator+` only works for an expression `a+b` when `a` is in fact an instance of `MyClass`, and not any other type; in particular, not `shared_ptr<MyClass>`. Why do you feel the need to use `shared_ptr` here in the first place? But if for some reason you insist, then like I said, you need a free-standing `operator+`, one that takes two parameters of type `shared_ptr<myClass>`.

Comment: I am new to smart pointers, and understanding its use cases. So, I am understanding how the operator overloading is implemented with smart pointers.

Comment: Operator overloading is usually *not* implemented with smart pointers. What you are trying to do is highly unusual, and frankly doesn't make much sense. And since the ultimate goal of the exercise is unclear, it's difficult to help you achieve it.

Comment: See if [this helps](https://godbolt.org/z/sb9fhcdoh)